# How to write to a log file on the website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, logfiles

I log actions to prove that certain tasks have been performed by specific users. Writing to a log file works in the development space (writing to C:\CPLogfile\ on my PC), but as soon as I publish the solution, I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application

My Code:

```
Public Sub LogAction(WhoIsThis As String, MessageToLog As String)

    Dim ThisPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
    Dim LogfileName As String = "logAction" & Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
    If InStr(ThisPath, "localhost") > 0 Then '----- Local machine
        LogfileName = "C:\CPLogfile\" & LogfileName
        If Not Directory.Exists("C:\CPLogfile") Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\CPLogfile\")
        End If
    Else
        LogfileName = ThisPath & "logAction" & Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt"
    End If
    Using w As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(LogfileName)
        w.Write("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
        w.WriteLine(", User: " & WhoIsThis)
        w.WriteLine("  :{0}", MessageToLog)
        w.WriteLine("-------------------------------")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the Stack Trace. That will help us see where the error is.

Comment: `Server Error in '/' Application` tells us nothing. When you get an error, you need to find out what the actual error message is and provide a stack trace. You can configure your application to log the errors with [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), log the errors in your `Application_Error` event (to a file, database, or sending an email), or configure the site to display the error directly on the page (not recommended for production use). Or if you own the server, you can check in the Windows event logs.

Comment: Agree with the previous two commenters on not enough information. Having said that, it's probably a permission problem. Locally you're probably using IISExpress or Casini, both of which run in the context of the currently logged-on user. On your production server you're running as the ASP.NET worker process, which has limited file-system permissions outside of the web site's folder structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason you cannot work outside of the IIS directories by default is a security issue. It stops things like transversal attacks. The reason you can on a development machine is most likely you are not using the full IIS product. When you move to IIS, you are restricted.

You have a couple of options:

1. Convince people to let you turn off the feature in IIS and open up a security hole in your server
2. Log to a database instead
3. Create a WCF service that writes the log file and set it up so it is not using IIS

There are other options, but these are the three easiest. The easiest is number 1, as it is a setting in IIS. I also would not recommend this solution.

Comment: As an aside, do you know how to debug an application so you can see the actual error from the application? Or, how to adjust the config so the real error appears on the page? Both would have led you to the answer much quicker than StackOverflow, except perhaps you have other people debugging your problem?

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the path cannot be accessed. However, to give the application write-privileges to the path, I need to know how to define the path, e.g.     HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host\logAction" & Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd") & ".txt", which produces the error.

Comment: @Dieter - By default IIS prevents you from accessing resources outside of the webroot. This is to avoid transversal attacks. On common attack years ago was to do something like:

../../../windows/system32/cmd.exe {command here}

as most people did not change the default directory for IIS. If you want to write to a file, a virtual path is the best way. If you need an absolute path, it needs to be a folder under IIS, or you have to turn off security (not recommended). You can set up an internal web service to log, as well.